# Advantages and disadvantages of original manuscript's page size in Word for the conversion process to Kindle

Tags: formatting

I was wondering if there is any advantage in the conversion process from Word to Kindle format if I create the Word document with any one particular page size? Would an original manuscript, created as a Word Document, with pages sized to 6" x 9" garner the same results as manuscript created with an 8" x 10" layout?

Comment: Kindle resize and repaginates the text of the fly depending on the device and the font size you choose so I doubt that the page layout you choose in Word will make any difference at all in the conversion to Kindle format.

Comment: What @MarkBaker meant is that Kindle .mobi eBook format (much like Apple's .epub) treat the text of the eBook as a continuous flow. Your choice of formatting (besides basic italic/bold etc.) matters little, and the eBook will re-paginate itself if the *reader* decides to change the font face or size.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out. If you download the [calibre ebook management program](https://calibre-ebook.com/), you can convert either format to kindle format. Then transfer it to your kindle either directly or by email and see what it looks like.